# positioning elements off screen with margins

Tags: html, css

I am working on animations with CSS and I had this question.

What is the correct way to position objects off screen to the left or right using `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties? Because, when I set `margin-left` to negative value it isn't positioned off screen. When I set the `margin-right` to some positive value it also isn't positioned off screen. It is only when I set those properties together I get the object going off screen completely like for example:

```css
#q_what_is {    /* example of setting the object off screen */
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-right: 370px; /* I left few pixels visible on purpose but setting it to -400px will put it off screen completely*/
}
```

My questions are:

- Why do I have to set both margins, why setting single margin does not work?
- What are the correct values to use for both (left and right) margins?
- Is this the correct way to position the object off screen for the purpose of animation?
- Will this method be compatible with other browsers besides Chrome or did I just found a bug?

This is my code:

```css
.question {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
}

.question_image {}

.answer {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: left;
}

.decor {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}

.decor_image {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
}

#q_what_is {
  /* example of setting the object off screen */
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-right: 370px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <div class="question">
    <span id="q_what_is" class="question_image" style="font-size: 20em;display: inline-block;"> &#9824;</span>
  </div>
  <div id="q_what_is_answer" class="answer">
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  </div>
  <div id="qu_what_is_decor_container" class="decor">
    <span id="q_what_is_decor" class="decor_image" style="font-size:20em;display:inline-block">&#9827;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

(in this example I replaced images with unicode characters for easiness)

Comment: A tip for you, **the best way to position objects** off screen would be using `css transform`.

Answer (score 2):

You have applied styles on the wrong element. When you set margin on inner span (i.e. inside div.question) the margin is set with respect to the container.

- You don't need to set both the margins.
- The correct values for margin-left and margin-right will depend on width of the html elements. For this case translateX equal to -391px.
- Margins are correct way to offset elements offscreen
- It is compatible with other browsers.

**Updated Code**

```css
.question {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
}

.question_image {}

.answer {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: left;
}

.decor {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}

.decor_image {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
}

#q_what_is {
  /* example of setting the object off screen */
  transform: translateX(-381px);
}
```

```html
 <div class="outer"style="width:100%">
 <div class="question">
  <span id="q_what_is" class="question_image" style="font-size: 20em;display: inline-block;"> &#9824;</span>
 </div>
 <div id="q_what_is_answer" class="answer">
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
</div>
<div id="qu_what_is_decor_container" class="decor">
  <span id="q_what_is_decor" class="decor_image" style="font-size:20em;display:inline-block">&#9827;</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: margin-left value may be different for different browsers.

Comment: hmmm. the problem with your changes to the code is that "bla bla bla" text is now moved considerably to the left. What I need to do, is the "bla bla bla" text to be positioned 400 pixels from the left margin of the BODY of the page and it should not move when animation is done. I think I am applying margin on the correct element, it is the margin of the image that I want to change, not the DIVs margin.

Comment: do you see the space that is there between the first "bla bla bla" and the left margin of the page? That space has to remain when you change the margin-left . I have tried many solutions but my case is difficult. I think the only way to make it, is to create another enclosing div, so I will have to have 2 enclosing divs, only to be able to animate by changing the margin-left propety

Comment: you can set margin-left in .answer class.

Comment: and then set the margin in the next element to the right which is decor? They are all left aligned. Could you please remove your answer because people thinks it is the correct one but it is not. You are breaking the layout I have.

Comment: updated my answer keeping your layout structure intact. You can always ask for a better solution than for deletion. :) I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: relative;` on that element and only use `left: -500px` (or whatever value), without the margin settings:

```css
.question {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
}

.question_image {}

.answer {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: left;
}

.decor {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}

.decor_image {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
}

#q_what_is {
  position: relative;
  left: -500px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <div class="question">
    <span id="q_what_is" class="question_image" style="font-size: 20em;display: inline-block;"> &#9824;</span>
  </div>
  <div id="q_what_is_answer" class="answer">
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  </div>
  <div id="qu_what_is_decor_container" class="decor">
    <span id="q_what_is_decor" class="decor_image" style="font-size:20em;display:inline-block">&#9827;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```